# Rails: Return distinct objects with at least one association meets a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Ok, I have 3 tables:

- `lessons`   : which has many new_words
- `new_words` : which belongs_to lesson,  and have a `word_type` column (Verb Adj Noun .etc)
- `verb_forms` :

  - every new words which has `word_type = Verb` will have 1 `verb_form` associated with.
  - `verb_forms` has a column `verb_type` which indicated the type of verb (1,2 or 3)

So now, I want to query all lessons that has at least 1 `Verb` that has `verb_type = 1`

So far, I've archived this:

```
class VerbForm < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :new_word

    scope :first_type, -> { where(verb_type: 1) }
end

class NewWord < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :verb_form, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :new_word

    scope :ftv, -> { verbs.joins(:verb_form).merge(VerbForm.first_type) }
end

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :new_words

    scope :with_ftvs, -> { joins(:new_words).merge(NewWord.ftv) }
end
```

Now, if i run `Lesson.with_ftvs`, each lesson will appear multi times depend on number of first-type verbs in that lesson (for example, if there are 3 first-type verbs in lesson 1, then `lesson 1` returned 3 times in above query)

So, how can I get distinct lessons list ?, I tried this query but it returned nil ?

```
    scope :with_ftvs, -> { joins(:new_words).merge(NewWord.ftv).distinct }
```

---

p/s: I was always thinking that `count` and `length` are the same. But when I try it with my original query: `Lesson.with_ftvs.count` vs `Lesson.with_ftvs.length`, they returns diffirent values:

[image]

Comment: `.count` does a SQL count query - and returns an integer. `.length` fetches the records and then measures the number of elements in the collection. `.size` does either depending on if the collection has been loaded already. http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/

Comment: as for nil from distinct. what is your rails version? distinct behaves differently in rails 3

Answer (score 0):

In SQL joins may return duplicated results so you should either use distinct or group by some column.

```
scope :with_ftvs, -> { joins(:new_words).merge(NewWord.ftv).group("lessons.id") }
# or
scope :with_ftvs, -> { joins(:new_words).merge(NewWord.ftv).distinct }
```